# How do i check if a field is empty or null with Tire gem on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to check with tire if a field is null.
Here is my query on my model.

```
def self.search(params)
  tire.search(load: true, match_all: {}, page: params[:page], per_page: 12) do
    query do
      boolean do 
        must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" }
        must { term :online, true }
        must_not { string 'name:Undefined' }
        must_not { term 'price:null' }
      end
    end
  end
end

must_not { term 'price:null' } is the code wich leads me to an error.
```

How can i do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
must_not { |m| m.term "price", nil }
```